What are the potential pitfalls of applying a daily statistical arbitrage model to intraday trading?
I've developed a statistical arbitrage (stat arb) model that works well on daily data. The model identifies mean reversion opportunities based on the spread between two related assets exceeding a certain threshold. I'm considering applying this same model to intraday trading, but I'm aware there might be differences between daily and intraday timeframes.
Could someone outline the potential pitfalls or challenges I might face when transitioning this daily stat arb model to an intraday setting? Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how factors like noise, volatility, market microstructure, and transaction costs might impact the effectiveness of the strategy when applied to intraday data. Any insights on how to adjust the model for intraday use would also be appreciated.
